# How to run single cucumber scenario by name

Tags: testing, gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm asking for help on how to run a feature file scenario just by name. I've been trying for a while and it does not come out. I know that can be done by tags or by line number, but I wonder if we can run a cucumber test by name, more or less with this nomenclature.

Given a file named "features/test.feature" with:

```
Feature: 
  Scenario: My first scenario
    Given this step is blah blah blah

  Scenario: My second scenario
    Given this step too blah blah
```

I want to run a scenario by name from the console or with gradle, maybe similar this way

```
cucumber features/test.feuture::My second scenario
```

Or maybe with gradle

```
./gradlew cucumber::My second scenario
```

Answer (score 8):

You didn't describe how you start cucumber so I can't help you with that.

- When used from the CLI accepts `--name REGEXP`. This will only run scenarios whose names match REGEXP.
- The `@CucumberOptions` annotation accepts `name="REGEXP"`.
- Cucumber < v6.0.0 looks at the environment. For maven you can add `-Dcucumber.options=--name REGEXP`. I don't know the equivalent for gradle. Take note that the escape characters maybe shell/build system dependent.
- Cucumber v6.0.0 and above looks at the environment. For maven you can add `-Dcucumber.filter.name="REGEXP"`.

See:

- https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java
- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-core#properties-environment-variables-system-options

Comment: I don't manage to make this work. I've got a Scenario like:

`Scenario Outline: Hello`
Examples:
| var |
| value 1|

Trying to run the test with the following values for `--name` but the framework doesn't find that 'Hello' test. Do you know how I could target it?

--name "Hello"
--name ^Hello$
--name *Hello*
--name "*Hello*"

Answer (score 1):

From cucumber 6.x, you can run a scenario with below CLI commands:

```
// Specify a scenario by its line number
$ cucumber-js features/my_feature.feature:3

// Specify a scenario by its name matching a regular expression
$ cucumber-js --name "topic 1"
```

But, these are time-consuming and repetitive. You can save a lot of time by using a dedicated VSCode Extension called [Cucumber-Quick](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AbhinabaGhosh.cucumberquick). This extension will allow you to run a scenario/feature just by right-clicking on them.  It can save you from all the hustle.

Comment: I don't manage to make this work. I've got a Scenario like:

`Scenario Outline: Hello`
Examples:
| var |
| value 1|

Trying to run the test with the following values for `--name` but the framework doesn't find that 'Hello' test. Do you know how I could target it?

--name "Hello"
--name ^Hello$
--name *Hello*
--name "*Hello*"

Answer (score 0):

You would call the scenario by its line number.

So assuming that the second scenario starts on line 5 in your feature file you could run:

```
cucumber features/test.feature:5
```